# Parse pinned objects not updating

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have the following code to update my objects that have changed on the server:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"getAllData" withParameters:@{@"LastUpdate": [self getLastSyncDate], @"Scan": @"NO"} block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error){        
    if (!error) {
        for (int x = 0; x < result.count; x++) {
            PFObject *object = [result objectAtIndex:x];
            [object unpinInBackgroundWithName:object.parseClassName block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
                if (!error) {
                    if ([object[@"deleted"] boolValue] != YES) {
                        [object pinInBackgroundWithName:object.parseClassName block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
                            if (x == result.count - 1) {
                                [self performSelector:@selector(reloadTableView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
                            }
                        }];
                    }
                }
            }];
        }
        [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"LastSynced"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
    [self reloadTableView];
}];
```

But my objects are not updating. Calling a PFQuery from the local datastore shows me the old versions.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a bunch of background functions nested in each other, and this is causing a racing error.

Here's the order of operations for your code:

1. Get the data
2. Iterate through each item for updates **and save changes in the background (this is key)**
3. Synchronize
4. Reload

Just getting to the end of the iteration does not mean that all the saves are complete - You need to wait until all the saves from step 2 are complete before you continue with steps 3 and 4.

A suggested order of operations:

1. Get the data
2. Set a global with the number of objects, and another global with the number that have been updated (starts at 0)
3. Iterate through each item for updates **and check with a function to see if all the updates are complete, i.e. do your two global equal each other. **Only if all updates are complete do you sync and reload**

Something like this:

```
//Declare these two globally
int total; 
int complete;


complete = 0;
*defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"getAllData" withParameters:@{@"LastUpdate": [self getLastSyncDate], @"Scan": @"NO"} block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error){        
    if (!error) {
        total = result.count;
        for (int x = 0; x < result.count; x++) {
            PFObject *object = [result objectAtIndex:x];
            [object unpinInBackgroundWithName:object.parseClassName block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
                if (!error) {
                    if ([object[@"deleted"] boolValue] != YES) {
                        [object pinInBackgroundWithName:object.parseClassName block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
                            self.total++;
                            [self updateCompleteCheck];
                        }];
                    }
                }
            }];
        }
    }
}];

-(void)updateCompleteCheck 
{
    if(total == complete) {
        //Only when this is done do you know, for certain, the update is really complete
        [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"LastSynced"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        [self reloadTableView];
    }
}
```